# Paypal subscription process flow

Tags: django, django-paypal

Im using paypal with Django. This is the scenario.
The user is logged in, he has not payed for the service. Once payed, I must update his user profile as "payed = True". Then he will have access to the full site.

Im struggeling to understand how this must be intergrated with paypal. I get the payments working successfully. But then how does my server know what user it will be fore when paypal bills the user?

Im thinking there must be a field for me to send to paypal, like a user id, and then paypal must send that to me when its doing a payment, so I can see which user it is?

How do you implement this with paypal?

Create the button

```
paypal_dict = {
    "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
    "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    "a3": "5.00",                      # monthly price
    "p3": 1,                           # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
    "t3": "M",                         # duration unit ("M for Month")
    "src": "1",                        # make payments recur
    "sra": "1",                        # reattempt payment on payment error
    "no_note": "1",                    # remove extra notes (optional)
    "item_name": "Test monthly subscription",
    "notify_url": "http://localhost:8000/payment/",
    "return_url": "http://localhost:8000/",
    "cancel_return": "http://localhost:8000/",
    "custom":request.user.get_profile().pk
}

# Create the instance.
ppform = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
```

Comment: I would be able to follow the steps below I think IF I can get this working!! Im so frustrated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551562/django-paypal-import-errors

Answer (score 2):

I think `payer id`  should fit to your needs.

> payer object
>
> This object includes information about the payer including payment
>   method, funding instruments, and details about the payer.

You can save id, and connect it with your user, then you will know which user should be billed, and use this id to make request to PayPal

Here is [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payer-object) for more info.

Comment: How would you connect the `payer_id` to the right user in the first place?

Comment: @knbk Do you mean before first payment?

Comment: The user presses a button, goes to paypal, pays, and that's when you first get the `payer_id`. I'm just not sure how you would connect the `payer_id`, which you first receive in the first IPN, to the user, which you only know when you generate the button.

Comment: So pretty much, how do you connect the signup to the user?

Comment: Ya, i see. I seems you are right at this point. He will need to put some unique value into subscribe button that after submition will be returned to server from paypal, and will give opportunity to identify user. Something like  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="19218">

Answer (score 1):

You can set an `"invoice"` to a unique value for each user. Make sure that the value is somehow saved and connected to the user. Each PayPal IPN for that specific subscription will contain the invoice id you sent through the paypal button.

See [HTML Variables for Recurring Payments Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU).

Comment: Should that be put in the paypal_dict?

Comment: "invoice":request.user.pk is what I was thinking

Comment: PayPal sais : This invoice has already been paid. For more information, please contact the merchant.

Comment: The invoice must be unique for each subscription. I'd create a model with an FK to the user, which saves a random uuid that you could use. This way, you won't have any trouble if they cancel their first subscription and get a new one later.

Comment: The invoice parameter would then be gotten in a signal right? Any idea whats wrong here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551562/django-paypal-import-errors